# Problema com retorno de um método Java

Tags: java

Este método está dando problema no retorno.  Está aparecendo uma mensagem de erro com o seguinte enunciado *missing return statement*. Alguém poderia me indica uma solução?

```
public String adicionar (String nome) {
    if(getNumLugares() < getNumDePassageiros())
        nomes.add(nome);
    else 
        return "Não ha lugares para mais passageiros";
 }
```

Comment: O que deveria ser retornado no caso de a adição ter sucesso?

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 12):

O seu método, devido ao `if`, tem dois caminhos possíveis para a execução seguir.

- 1º caminho, caso a condição seja verdadeira

  ```
  if(getNumLugares() < getNumDePassageiros())
      nomes.add(nome);
  ```
- 2º caminho, caso a condição seja falsa

  ```
  return "Não ha lugares para mais passageiros";
  ```

Um método cuja assinatura indique que deve retornar um valor tem de utilizar, em todos os possíveis caminhos de execução,  a palavra `return` para finalizar esse caminho.

No seu código, o erro acontece porque no 1º caminho não foi utilizado o `return`.

Altere, para incluir o `return`.

```
public String adicionar (String nome) {
    if(getNumLugares() < getNumDePassageiros()){
        nomes.add(nome);
        return "Adicionado"; //"Adicionado" ou outra coisa qualquer
    }
    return "Não há lugares para mais passageiros";
}
```

<sub>**Nota:** Você utiliza uma string como valor de retorno para indicar o sucesso ou não da execução do mesmo o que pode não ser a melhor abordagem.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

O erro:

> missing return statement

Ou em tradução livre:

> declaração de retorno faltando

Ocorre quando um método é declarado com retorno e existem possibilidades deste valor de retorno não ser atingido.

No seu caso o método está declarado com o retorno de uma `String` (`public String adicionar (String nome) {`) e no seu `else` este retorno está sendo respeitado. Porém no `if` não há nenhum retorno, ou seja, quando a condição `getNumLugares() < getNumDePassageiros()` é executada nenhum `return` acontece, desrespeitando a declaração.

O meio para resolver o seu problema, a grosso modo, é adicionar a instrução `return` dentro do `id`, que pode ser realizado da seguinte forma:

```
public String adicionar(String nome) {
  if (getNumLugares() < getNumDePassageiros()) {
    nomes.add(nome);
    return nome;
  } else {
    return "Não há lugares para mais passageiros";
  }
}
```

Porém é importante salientar que tudo depende da forma como seu método é executado, o que pode exigir que o return seja feito de forma diferente. Você pode retornar um status:

```
return "Passageiro adicionado.";
```

Você pode retornar nulo caso não exista observação:

```
return null;
```

Ou, como no exemplo, retornar o nome do passageiro adicionado:

```
return nome;
```

Talvez no seu caso seja interessante quebrar o método em mais partes, com uma validação retornando um `Boolean`, porém é como disse anteriormente: Depende da aplicação que será dada para o método.